# Hive - JobTracking?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, thrift, hive

I've been through the methods, but I can't seem to find out how to extrapolate the % completed (like an eventListener!) of a job in Hive.  Please help!  EDIT - I thought you can get "I'm done mapping...so I'm 50% completed" from the Client (If I were to have submitted a command OVERWRITE EXTERNAL TABLE). OpsCenter with Brisk (by Datastax) does this very thing.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServerException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive.Client;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;

public class Hive {

    static Client client;
    static TSocket transport;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws HiveServerException,
            TException, MetaException {

        transport = new TSocket("hiveserver",
                10000);
        transport.setTimeout(999999999);

        TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        client = new ThriftHive.Client(protocol);
        transport.open();

        System.out.println("Starting map job...");

        Thread mapReduceThread = new Thread(new HiveQuery(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myHiveTable"));
        mapReduceThread.start();

        System.out.println("Waiting on map...");
    }

    private static class HiveQuery implements Runnable {

        private String hql;

        public HiveQuery(String hql) {
            this.setHql(hql);
        }

        public void run() {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Blocking
            try {
                client.execute(this.getHql());
            } catch (HiveServerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            List<String> responseList = null;
            try {
                responseList = client.fetchAll();
            } catch (HiveServerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            float elapsedTime = elapsedTimeMillis / 1000F;

            System.out.println("Job took: " + elapsedTime + " seconds");

            for (String response : responseList) {
                System.out.println("Response: " + response);
            }

            transport.close();
            System.out.println("Closed transport");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public void setHql(String hql) {
            this.hql = hql;
        }

        public String getHql() {
            return hql;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since the query itself is blocking, I'm not sure if there is a way to get more info on the job. Have you been able to get more information from hive? I'm looking for jobId and possibly the % stuff..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by extrapolate?

I don't think you can deduce anything by the % completed figure in Hadoop except for the fact that if it goes up, then more work has happened. You can't say "oh that means I have 20 seconds left" or anything like that.

Comment: I thought you could get "I'm done mapping...so I'm 50% completed" from it.  OpsCenter/Brisk for Cassandra does this.

Comment: Which is probably something I should have stated originally :)